# Vala GLib Setting Changed

Tags: events, background, glib, vala

I have the following code, which correctly prints the picture-uri of the background. I can't get updated when the background changes, however. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var background_settings = new GLib.Settings ("org.gnome.desktop.background");

string picturi = background_settings.get_string ("picture-uri");

stdout.printf("\n\n\n\n\n" + picturi + "\n\n\n\n\n");

background_settings.changed.connect (() => {
    stdout.printf("\n\n\n\n\nBackground Changed\n\n\n\n\n\n");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. The problem must be somewhere else.

The only thing you would need to make that code into a working test case is adding a GLib main loop (which is required for the changed callback to get called). Are you running a main loop?